# Payfast sandbox notify_url to localhost

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, payment-gateway

The question might be simple for you but i am new to the **laravel payment integration** and i am stuck at this. I do have a problem with **laravel** - **payfast** payment integration.

The question is, How to set the `notify_url` to my **localhost** address for **payfast** payment integration in laravel 5.3 testing.

Or any idea about how to test the **ITN call back in test environment**.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit the same issue and realised that there is no way that the localhost URL will work. There is no way for Payfast to reach that address.

2 Options - you could use a proxy server to map your external IP address to a domain.

OR

Dev offline as far as possible and then deploy to a online test environment to test.

Comment: ngrok is another solution that works well for local development - https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0):

for people who still need an answer to this question, using ngrok helped make my localhost publicly accessible, try it

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It would help future users if you could edit your answer to include exactly what you need to do with ngrok to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to open a tunnel that creates access to your localhost endpoint from outside your network.

To setup:

1. Download and run the command line tool
2. In the tool run : `ngrok config add-authtoken [your_secret_token]`
3. Once that is done, head to the `Tunnels` > `Agents` tab and see your tunnel
4. Copy the tunnel url e.g `https://394a-116-154-29-75.ngrok-free.app/api/myendpoint` and use it as the URL for 3rd party apps to access your localhost

Easy peasy